# Using reduce() in defining new string methods

Tags: javascript, function, reduce

I am having trouble re-factoring my solution to the "Jaden Casing Strings" kata on codewars. The problem is to capitalize the first letter of every word of a given sentence, like this:

Not Jaden-Cased: "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"

Jaden-Cased:     "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"

Here is my solution:

```
function jayden (sen) {
  sen = sen.split('').reduce(function (str, next, ind) {
    return str + (!sen[ind - 1] || sen[ind - 1] === ' ' ? next.toUpperCase() : next);
  }, '');
  return sen
}

String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    return jayden(this)
}
```

Ideally I would like to have the contents of the `jayden` function inside of `String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {` but I can't seem to iterate through `this`. Is it possible to iterate through `this`?

Comment: I realize this is just for a small kata, but you really shouldn't ever edit the prototype. Either create your own that inherits `String`, or just use the named function you've created. When you work with other people, It sets applications up for a world of pain when everyone starts adding whatever they want to the prototypes of primitives: `String.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {return "GOT YOU GOOD!!!!" }`

Comment: In a method on `String.prototype`, `this` is the string, and you can do anything you could do with a string. What isn't working for you?

Comment: @torazaburo After reading your comment I realized the mistake that I made in the first place. I was trying to iterate through `this` as if it were `this.split('')`, which is an array of strings, rather than a string. Thank you!

Comment: Another option is to do `Array.prototype.reduce.call(this`, because even though there is no `reduce` defined on strings, `reduce` **does** handle it as an array of characters if you call it this way.

Comment: you can just replace with a callback and avoid all the array sillyness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it, in a more simple way:

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    return this.split(" ").map(function(x){
       return x[0].toUpperCase()+x.slice(1);
    }).join(" ");
}
console.log("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real".toJadenCase())
```

Another example using `reduce()`:

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
  return this.split('').reduce(function (str, next, index) {
    return str+(str[index-1]==" "?next.toUpperCase():next)        
  });
}
console.log("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real".toJadenCase())
```

How does the second example work:

Each time `str` is the current part of string without a last char. The last char is `next`. Here's the breakdown, how `str` and `next` change with each iteration. Before the comma is `str`, after is `next`.

```
    H,o
    Ho,w
    How, 
    How ,c
    How C,a
    How Ca,n
    How Can, 
    How Can ,m
    How Can M,i
    How Can Mi,r
    How Can Mir,r
    How Can Mirr,o
    How Can Mirro,r
    How Can Mirror,s
    How Can Mirrors, 
    How Can Mirrors ,b
    How Can Mirrors B,e
    How Can Mirrors Be,
```

The logic is: return str+next, if str doesn't end with a space (i.e. `str[index-1]`, which is the last char, is a space). If `str` ends with a space, then `next` is a the first letter of new string. Then it's capitalized. So, in this case we're returning `str+next.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Thanks. I'm a beginner at javascript and I wrote it the way that I did so I could practice using reduce. Do you know if it would be possible to write this using reduce?

Comment: @Jeremy Added another example, now with `.reduce()`.

Comment: That's an awful lot of spreading and popping. Wouldn't it be clearer to write it as `reduce(function(str, next, i, orig) { return str + (orig[i-1] === " " ? next.toUpperCase() : next);`?

Comment: @Jeremy See an additional explanation for details :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are some people trying to write code which will contribute to global warming.

```
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function(s) {
    s=s||this;
    var a = s.split(" "), i=0;
    while(a[i])a[i]=a[i].replace(a[i][0],a[i++][0].toUpperCase());
        return a.join(" ");
}
```

Can be used both ways, for a string such as:
`var str = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"`
you can go:

`str.toJadenCase();`

but not restricted to, if needed and when needed the alternative

`"".toJadenCase(str);`

will be available.

Comment: Could you explain the global warming comment? Is it because some of the functions are inefficient?

Comment: yes, in most of them as you can see use excessive processing overhead or at least 10 times greater than necessary; one of them is writing and rewriting every single bit of the string content in the process of capitalizing few starting letters.

Answer (score 0):

That works this easy way :

```
var str = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";
var jayden = str.split(" ").map(x => x[0].toUpperCase().concat(x.slice(1))).join(" ");

console.log(jayden); // How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real
```

Comment: His question relates to how to package this onto the `String` prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your question, return an immediately invoked anonymous function rather than invoking a named function:

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
  return function (sen) {
    return sen.split('').reduce(function (str, next, ind) {
      return str + (!sen[ind - 1] || sen[ind - 1] === ' ' ? next.toUpperCase() : next);
    }, '');
  }(this);
};

console.log("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real".toJadenCase());
```

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, not necessary. I'm answering the question points: "trouble re-factoring" and "the contents of the jayden function inside ...prototype...".

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to isolate the logic for `toJadenCase` from the String prototype you can reference on method `toJadenCase` to `this`, and then change `this` value from inside String prototype. Like...

```js
function jayden () {
  var self = this;
  self = self.split('').reduce(function (str, next, ind) {
    return str + (!self[ind - 1] || self[ind - 1] === ' ' ? next.toUpperCase() : next);
  }, '');  
  return self;
}
```

And then define toJadenCase in String prototype as...

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
    return jayden.call(this);
};
```

Check the console of this [JS Bin example.](http://jsbin.com/gamofowuxe/edit?js,output)